# Deleting a directory in c#

Tags: c#, file-io

I am trying to delete a specific directory from mY temp folder

```
    try
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path + "uniquePdf\\");

        string[] direct = Directory.GetDirectories(path + "uniquePdf\\");
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
            File.Delete(file);
        }
        Directory.Delete(path);
    }
```

the path variable points to the temp folder, and uniquePdf is a folder i made inside of there. How do i delete this folder on closing the application? The above method seems to throw an exception at

```
Directory.Delete(path);
```

Do i need to do

```
Directory.Delete(path + "uniquePdf\\");
```

Comment: When you say "The above method seems to throw an exception" in a question on SO it's usually a good idea to include details of the exception you are seeing; it will help people answer your question.

Comment: in future i will, the answers below haveworked, shall i go back and get the error and paste it in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Always use Path.Combine() to create paths
2. Deleting when closing the application can be done however when an application is terminated the code won't run so I advise you to empty/recreate the folder on startup of the application.
3. Yes you need to delete all the files.

Please specify the exception you get to help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

`Directory.Delete` has an overload which takes a second parameter, `bool recursive`. You might want to use: `System.IO.Directory.Delete(path + "uniquePdf", true);`

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
Directory.Delete(Path.Combine(path, "uniquePdf"), true);
```

If you got an exception, it would be good to know what kind of exception you got. Maybe you still have one of the files opened within the folder. So make sure you put all your file handling into a  `using()` statement or you called `file.Close()` before you started to delete the directory.

Comment: He gets an exception because the badly named 'path' is his system temp directory, and he's trying to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `Directory.Delete(Path.Combine(path, "uniquePdf"), true);`

As others have said, use Path.xxx functions to play with paths, don't do string concatenation, and don't worry about witchcraft like trailing slashes.